# Azure Disk Space VM wise

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, disk

We have a scenario wherein we are trying to fetch the attached disk VM wise and the respective the total space assigned to these disks. Is there any command or script to get the detail?

I have used the command `Get-AzureDisk` to get the output but it does not display all the VMs that I have in my list. Not sure why, any solution?

Comment: ARM vms? or classic VM?

Comment: Please specify for Both cases I tried using PS file to load the subscription and then fetch the details .The Azure subscription is registered with Resource Manager model.

Comment: Is this even possible in Azure as for AWS I was able to fetch it directly from the console but in Azure I don't see any such feature.

Comment: we can use PowerShell to get the disk size, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using PS file to load the subscription

We can use this script to login azure account:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "your password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($accountName, $password)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential
```

About disks, we can use powershell to get OS disk size and data disk size:
**data disk**:

```
PS C:\Users> $a = (get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName vm -Name jasonvm)
PS C:\Users> $a.StorageProfile.DataDisks


Name            : jasonvm-20170428-161615
DiskSizeGB      : 20
Lun             : 0
Caching         : None
CreateOption    : Empty
SourceImage     :
VirtualHardDisk :
```

About **OS disk**, if you have **not** resize OS disk, **Linux and windows OS disk  are 30 GB** (if your windows VM created before 2017.2, the OS disk size is 127GB, Linux is 30GB):
If you have resize the OS disk, we can use this script to get the size:

```
PS C:\Users> $vm = get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName vm -Name jasonvm
PS C:\Users> $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
100
```

If can't return any result, it means your OS size set by default.[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.